# Transactonal Email Trigger vs Journey Builder vs Transactional API

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My team is in the process of moving over all email activity and setup from 1.0 to 2.0 and one of the main differences is the use of Journey Builder. We currently have live Purchase Data flowing through via an API Event Entry in Journey Builder that then goes into a data extension.

My question is should we stick with the Trigger Sends we use now for transactional emails like in 1.0 or switch to Journey Builder using the API event entry or should we be using the transactional email API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marketing Cloud is moving to focus more heavily on Journey Builder.
If you are migrating activities have the skill/ability to rebuild in Journey Builder using the Event APIs - I recommend doing this.

If you are doing simple "thank you for your purchase" emails and don't care about tracking/reporting - the Transnational API will be sufficient.
If you want the ability to track/report (or make decisions based on their opens/clicks, upsell/cross-sell activity), then use Journey Builder.

Reference: [Transnational Messaging APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm)